# how to filter data in datagrid view with multiple comboboxes

Tags: vb.net

Okay..So, I was trying to create a filter on the datagrid using comboboxes. I was able to create a filtration process for only one combo box. What I wanted to do is to filter the filtered data in the datagrid but i don't know how. I already tried some ways that I thought could solve the issue but, no luck so far. Basically I have 4 combo boxes for the filtration. For example, the first combo box is for Province then I still want to filter the search into Municipality then to Districts and to Years.
So, the user will be able to sort or filter his search from the database.

This is are the codes that I'm stock on. The code for the Year is actually giving me a system.int32 error. so I'm still fixing it. It's just the same code actually.

Thanks for the help.!

```js
Try
                Dim view As New DataView(dataset)
                view.RowFilter = String.Format("PENRO like '%{0}%'", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = view
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

```js
 Try
                Dim view As New DataView(dataset)
                view.RowFilter = String.Format("CENRO like '%{0}%'", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = view
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

```js
Try
                Dim view As New DataView(dataset)
                view.RowFilter = String.Format("DISTRICT like '%{0}%'", ComboBox7.SelectedItem)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = view
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you concatenate the values of the filters?

For example:

```
view.RowFilter = String.Format("DISTRICT like '%{0}%'", ComboBox7.SelectedItem) & " AND " & _

String.Format("CENRO like '%{0}%'", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
```

I don't usually use String.Format, I prefer using custom made string, but it should work.

Comment: well, that worked but when i tried to create a filter for three comboboxes i get an error..syntax error: missing operand after 'andPENRO' operator. code goes like this .....                 view.RowFilter = String.Format("Convert(YEAR,'System.String') Like '%{0}%'", ComboBox3.SelectedItem) & " AND " & String.Format("District like '%{0}%'", ComboBox7.SelectedItem) & "and" & String.Format("PENRO like '%{0}%'", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)

Comment: You need a whitespace between **'and' and 'PENRO'** just like SQL sintax

Comment: it's fixed, this is what i did..                view.RowFilter = String.Format("Convert(YEAR,'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' AND District LIKE '%{1}%' AND CENRO LIKE '%{2}%'", ComboBox3.SelectedItem, ComboBox7.SelectedItem, ComboBox2.SelectedItem)